# Extending Eigen Library to Include Sorting

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to extend the C++ Eigen library to include a command v.sort(); I'm using the EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN based approach outlined [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html).

The code below (in my "MatrixBaseAddons.h") does not work, because the "result" object does not get loaded with a copy of "this"---in the debugger, "result.rows()" is an uninitialized value not equal to derived()->rows(). How do I actually make a copy of "this" and put it in "result"?

```
// DOES NOT WORK
MatrixBase<Derived> sort(bool ascending = true) const {
    MatrixBase<Derived> result = derived();
    result.sortInPlace(ascending);
    return result;
}

// WORKS!
void sortInPlace(bool ascending = true) {
    std::sort(derived().data(), derived().data() + derived().size());
    if (!ascending)
        this->reverseInPlace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MatrixBase` is an abstract class. You need to return a `Matrix<>` object with appropriate scalar type and sizes. You can directly use the typedef `PlainObject` for that:

```
PlainObject sort(bool ascending = true) const {
  PlainObject res = derived();
  ...
  return res;
}
```